# IDataReader for Generic Access

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I'm trying to make a "Helper" class where you simply pass the driver and the parameters and the class does the connection and connection string assembly for you.

I've been using the interfaces from System.Data like IDataReader, IDbConnection.

Now after testing it with MySQL the code is working perfectly but as soon as I point and configure it for SQL Server (Microsoft) it does not return any processed rows. I have done some debugging and the info from the SQL server is appearing in the IDataReader but it seems I can't Iterate over it ?

My Current Code:

Connect Method in Helper Class

```
try
{
    factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(driver);
    _con = factory.CreateConnection();
    _con.ConnectionString = buildConnectionString.ToString();
    _con.Open();
}
catch (System.Data.Common.DbException ex)
{
    _con = null;
    throw ex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _con = null;
    throw ex;
}
return _con;
```

A the moment I'm passing my driver as **System.Data.SqlClient** for SQL Server and **MySql.Data.MySqlClient** for MySQL.

```
System.Data.IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (reader.Read())
{
    System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    // Insert info from Reader into the Row
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

reader.Close();
```

I suspects it has something to do with how IDataReader is trying to handle the types but can't find any documentation on this as it's working perfectly for MySQL but not for SQL Server? Any Help?

Comment: unrelated, but your error handling is doing nothing particularly useful, and lots of harm - in particular, aren't disposing the connection in the error case, and you are destroying the stacktrace. A single `catch { if(conn != null) { conn.Dispose(); } throw; }` would be far preferable, IMO

Comment: with the reader code shown, do you ever get inside the `while(reader.Read())` block? if not, I suspect your SQL is to blame; that should work...

Comment: Thanks for the tip will change it accordingly.

Comment: I have run the code in SQL Server Manager and it returned the rows as expected. I then debugged and found that I could see the values of the rows in the DataReader (When I inspected it) but it was skipping the block entirely. And as stated MySQL behaves normally.

Comment: you aren't giving us much to go on here, and my psychic debugger isn't working. Can you give some example TSQL that does this? Also, what does `reader.GetType().Name` display, out of curiosity? If I had to guess, the way you are parameterising the command (not shown **at all**) is probably leading to no rows returned, perhaps due to nulls. But I'm guessing here, as all the interesting code is in the command setup.

Comment: watch out; if you've observed the data via the debugger, then **you've consumed it** and it is gone. Avoid doing that.

Comment: Got it! Feel like a idiot but learned a few things things from you :D. Never updated the query (Our Input) when I moved my test to SQL Server. Was asking for * FROM {table} LIMIT 100 from SQL Server changed it to SELECT TOP 100 * FROM {table} and it worked. Sigh. Could you move your one comment about "SQL is to blame" to a answer you were totally right ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't giving many clues here, since most of the interesting code here is *probably* around the command setup. If, at execution, it never enters the `while (reader.Read()) {...}` block, then it is *probably* TSQL or parameter related (especially nulls, which can easily result in no rows).

Since your data is `DataTable`-centric and you already have the provider-factory, another possibility here is to use `CreateDataAdapter()` from the factory, and let the factory worry about the binding of TSQL to a `DataTable`. Otherwise, treble-check that the TSQL you are providing is valid, sensible, and correctly parameterised.

Ultimately, the `Read()` loop itself is fine, and is pretty-much what all materialization routines do. It is, for example, very close to how dapper works, and that works fine over a range of databases.